# How to check if session object contains any object at all?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

In my session object, I have various items which can be accessed by:

```
req.session.foo;
req.session.bar;
req.session.baz;
```

etc!

My questions is, rather than do something like this:

```
if(req.session.foo || req.session.bar || req.session.baz..){
    //Do something
}
```

Is there a way to check that req.session contains any object at all (foo, bar, baz etc, without having to check each one individually ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this `if(Object.keys(req.session).length > 0)`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(Object.keys(req.session).length) {
    // do something;
}
```

// if there would any key, then length would be positive number, if not then it return 0 so program wouldn't enter into if block. this would be less time complex as this is saving comparison time